# Flutter animation showing and hiding a container

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

I'm actually working on a new app and i'm currently blocked on an animation behaviour.

this is my code

```
class SearchAppBar extends ConsumerStatefulWidget
    implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final Size size;

  const SearchAppBar({super.key, required this.size});
  @override
  _SearchAppBarState createState() => _SearchAppBarState();

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => size;
}

class _SearchAppBarState extends ConsumerState<SearchAppBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  List<String>? cats;
  double _initialValue = 80;
  @override
  void initState() {
    SitesRepositoryImpl()
        .getSiteCategoriesInLocation(longitude: 0, latitude: 0)
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        cats = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  bool animate = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.listen(appBarHeightProvider, (previous, next) {
      setState(() {
        _initialValue = next;
        animate = true;
      });
    });
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 16,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              border:
                  Border.all(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2), width: 1)),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                width: 16,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/search.svg",
                  theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: CustomColors.darkBlue),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 16,
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 7,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Text(
                        "Recherche",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Stolzl',
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: Colors.grey.shade600),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _searchController,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: "A proximité, Tous les catégories...",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Stolzl',
                                color: CustomColors.darkBlue,
                                fontSize: 12)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer()
                    /*SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                    )*/
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: CustomColors.greyBorderColor,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/icons/filter.svg",
                    theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: CustomColors.darkBlue),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          height: _initialValue - 80,
          color: Colors.white,
          curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
          child: CategoryTabsWidget(
            height: _initialValue - 80,
            cats: cats,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The behaviour that is needed is :

- i open the draggableScrollSheet, the app bar must start expanding and showing the TabBar, and when i close the draggableScrollSheet, the app bar must start shrinking and hiding the tabBar.

Any help is much appreciated.